# How can I split a string along with space?

Tags: c#, string, split

```
string arg = "-h 127.0.0.1 -p 50 cssbct  \"hey man!\"\r\n";
```

How can I split the above string so that I can obtain an array of strings of 6 elements such that

```
splittedArgs[0] == "-h"
splittedArgs[0] == "127.0.0.1"
splittedArgs[0] == "-p"
splittedArgs[0] == "50"
splittedArgs[0] == "cssbct"
splittedArgs[0] == "\"hey man!\""
```

?

I have tried like the following:

```
args = args.Replace('\r', ' ');
args = args.Replace('\n', ' ');
string[] splittedArgs = args.Split(new string[] { " " }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

It didn't work.

Any idea?

---

N.B. The string can also come in the following forms:

```
string arg = "-h 127.0.0.1 cssbct  \"hey man!\" -p 50\r\n";
string arg = "cssbct \"hey man!\" -p 50 -h 127.0.0.1 \r\n";
```

The elements will have to maintain the sequence accordingly.

Comment: Have you already had a look at the countless questions about [parsing `args`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+parse+args)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to split on the white space gaps.

You were on the right lines with `string split` using `" "` but given you example string of:

`string arg = "-h 127.0.0.1 -p 50 cssbct  \"hey man!\"\r\n";`, there is a variable amount of white-space.

A [REGEX - Regular Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) can be used to break up a string based on varying white-space. Below we use `\\s+` to fulfil this using [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.8).

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string arg = "-h 127.0.0.1 -p 50 cssbct  \"hey man!\"\r\n";
        string[] arrArgs = Regex.Split(arg, "\\s+");
        foreach(string s in arrArgs){
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This mechanism is unable to split the following: `"POST /cssbct HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: locationserver\r\nContent-Length: 72\r\n<optional header lines>\r\nname=cssbct&location=RB-999"`